# Morse index in variational calculus

Tags: calculus-of-variations, morse-theory

Let $f(t,x,v)$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathcal{C}_{x,y}$ be the set of smooth paths $c:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $c(0)=x,c(1)=y$, $E(c)$ be a functional on $\mathcal{C}_{x,y}$ given by $\displaystyle E(c)=\int_0^1 f(t,c(t),\dot c(t)) dt$.

A path $c$ is critical, if the derivative of $E$ at $c$ is zero: $D_cE(\delta c)=0$ for all variations $\delta c\in T_c \mathcal{C}_{x,y}$ fixing the two endpoints. We consider the second derivative of $E$ at critical paths: $D^2_cE$, which is a symmetric bilinear form on $T_c \mathcal{C}_{x,y}$.

The Morse index $i(c)$ of $c$ is defined as the supremum of $\dim L$, where $L$ is a linear subspace of $T_c \mathcal{C}_{x,y}$ on which $D^2_cE$ is negative definite.

The index $i(c)$ may not be finite, since $\mathcal{C}_{x,y}$ is infinite dimensional. There is a sufficient condition. That is, let $H=\partial_v^2 f$ be the Hessian matrix of $f$ with respect to the second variable $v$.

- If $H(t,c(t),\dot c(t))$ is positive definite for all $t\in[0,1]$, then $i(c)$ is finite.

This proposition can be found in Professor Duistermaat's [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870876900748). I am not familiar with this and couldn't follow his argument.

How would you prove this property? I also want to know if there are some standard references for this proposition. Thanks!

Comment: The heart of the proof is the fact that the  operator $-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+  w(t)$  on functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying the Dirichlet condition, is selfadjoint, it has compact resolvent and its spectrum is bounded from below. Thus, it can only have finitely many negative eigenvalues.